# XMLStarlet - How to select Element data with double nameSpace

Tags: xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm tryign to select Element data using XMLStarlet and i'm unable to do so...

I'm able to select attribute but not the element and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong:

**`sample.xml`**:

```
<Response xmlns:r="http://test1" xmlns:c="http://test2" 
    <r:UniqueIDList>
      <c:UniqueID type="INTERNAL">123456789</c:UniqueID>
      <c:UniqueID type="INTERNAL" source="ID">987654321</c:UniqueID>
    </r:UniqueIDList>
```

Code i'm using to extract

```
 xml sel -N c="http://test2" -N r="http://test1" -t -m "//r:UniqueIDList/c:*" -v @type -n sample.xml
```

I will receive the INTERNAL INTERNAL, but cannot figure out how can i select the actual UniqueID

Expected output:
    123456789
    987654321

Ideally i would only want to see the 1st only...

any help is much appreciated.

After further testing i managed to get this going...

```
   xml sel -N c="http://test2" -N r="http://test1" -t -v "//r:UniqueIDList/c:UniqueID sample.xml
```

which works fine.

**Can you advise if it's possible to extract *just* the 1st value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i have managed to figure it out..

Not sure if this is the correct way, but this can be achieved using the following:

```
 xml sel -N c="http://test2" -N r="http://test1" -t -v "//r:UniqueIDList/c:UniqueID[position()=1]" sample.xml
```