# Extract element from XML with namespace using xmlstarlet

Tags: bash, shell, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

What is the xmlstarlet syntax to extract the string "BkDHOZICQpereh46o84yUQ|mwu76ctmJWcf6heNsvNBudrAaia9xEQH" from the following XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.12.xsd">
    <credentials token="BkDHOZICQpereh46o84yUQ|mwu76ctmJWcf6heNsvNBudrAaia9xEQH">
        <site id="478d0aef-142d-456b-94d5-9a8919d85e82" contentUrl=""/>
        <user id="2e713141-0da2-471b-b2ac-8ae3974b4df5"/>
    </credentials>
</tsResponse>
```

Comment: See: [XMLStarlet - How to select Element data with double nameSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26027334/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

```
xmlstarlet sel -N api=http://tableau.com/api -t -v //api:credentials/@token -n response.xml
```