# xmlstarlet extract group info with subnode

Tags: csv, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I need to extract group info from a complex XML file, then loop through the groups to perform some changes, but I'm not able to get data in a clean way to loop through. Tried a lot, seen a lot of examples, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Given the following XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.12.xsd">
    <pagination pageNumber="1" pageSize="100" totalAvailable="12"/>
    <groups>
        <group id="74c29008-7550-11eb-94d7-73020b27aff3" name="Todos os usuários">
            <domain name="local"/>
        </group>
        <group id="e392c24a-535d-4e78-8463-0a492d61c317" name="Tbv_Vs_Operacoes">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="Viewer" grantLicenseMode="onLogin"/>
        </group>
        <group id="6c236376-aa1b-451e-8b63-488387aac20b" name="Tbv_Alertas_Inteligentes">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="Viewer" grantLicenseMode="onLogin"/>
        </group>
        <group id="58c86b3e-e1b2-46e5-9acf-43335de1c58d" name="TBE_VS_OPERACOES">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="ExplorerCanPublish" grantLicenseMode="onLogin"/>
        </group>
        <group id="89c33fb6-dce9-4097-9be8-f01d502cc11b" name="Tbl_Server_Admin_Creator">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="SiteAdministratorExplorer" grantLicenseMode="onLogin"/>
        </group>
        <group id="306dac3b-a377-451f-9283-c7be3533e02f" name="Tbv_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="Viewer" grantLicenseMode="onSync"/>
        </group>
        <group id="9259961c-3ca7-4c1a-9c44-374a4555c270" name="Tbe_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios">
            <domain name="university.net"/>
            <import domainName="university.net" siteRole="Explorer" grantLicenseMode="onSync"/>
        </group>
    </groups>
</tsResponse>
```

How to get an output like the csv below, with one row per group and 4 columns: id, name, siteRole and grantlicenseMode?

```
74c29008-7550-11eb-94d7-73020b27aff3,Todos os usuários,,
e392c24a-535d-4e78-8463-0a492d61c317,Tbv_Vs_Operacoes,Viewer,onLogin
6c236376-aa1b-451e-8b63-488387aac20b,Tbv_Alertas_Inteligentes,Viewer,onLogin
58c86b3e-e1b2-46e5-9acf-43335de1c58d,TBE_VS_OPERACOES,ExplorerCanPublish,onLogin
...
```

I managed to output the values inside the "group" node with the following command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N api=http://tableau.com/api -T -t -m //api:group -v "concat(@id,';',@name,';',import/@siteRole,';',import/@grantLicenseMode)" -n groups.xml
74c29008-7550-11eb-94d7-73020b27aff3;Todos os usuários;;
e392c24a-535d-4e78-8463-0a492d61c317;Tbv_Vs_Operacoes;;
6c236376-aa1b-451e-8b63-488387aac20b;Tbv_Alertas_Inteligentes;;
58c86b3e-e1b2-46e5-9acf-43335de1c58d;TBE_VS_OPERACOES;;
89c33fb6-dce9-4097-9be8-f01d502cc11b;Tbl_Server_Admin_Creator;;
306dac3b-a377-451f-9283-c7be3533e02f;Tbv_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios;;
9259961c-3ca7-4c1a-9c44-374a4555c270;Tbe_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios;;
6ed1b848-3206-4723-8b3b-7721a9869f53;Tbe_VS_Financeiro;;
701a819f-f176-4807-ad2c-572b970a9f8f;Tbv_VS_Financeiro;;
232613c8-9129-493c-b2af-a65c1d82d88a;Tbe_VS_Consumidor_CRM;;
c9346a0e-4f7a-4e53-95b4-71d7ef4c4e3b;Tbe_Vs_Demanda_e_Abastecimento;;
f8345037-4153-4303-bdb7-39ca3bee32ee;QlikSense_Sustent_BI;;
```

but as you can see above, I'm not able to get the values for @siteRole and @grantLicenseMode, that are both on the subnode "import".

Comment: This might help: [Extract element from XML with namespace using xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69681793/3776858) (question from you) and [Use sed to concatenate xml tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69721834/3776858)

Comment: Sorry about that @Cyrus, I just edited and complemented the question, narrowing it down to the subnode problem. Do you have an idea about how to reference the subnode values inside de 'concat'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
xmlstarlet select -N x="http://tableau.com/api" --text --template \
  --match "//x:tsResponse/x:groups/x:group" \
  --value-of "concat(@id,',',@name,',',x:import/@siteRole,',',x:import/@grantLicenseMode)" \
  -n file.xml
```

Output:

```
74c29008-7550-11eb-94d7-73020b27aff3,Todos os usuários,,
e392c24a-535d-4e78-8463-0a492d61c317,Tbv_Vs_Operacoes,Viewer,onLogin
6c236376-aa1b-451e-8b63-488387aac20b,Tbv_Alertas_Inteligentes,Viewer,onLogin
58c86b3e-e1b2-46e5-9acf-43335de1c58d,TBE_VS_OPERACOES,ExplorerCanPublish,onLogin
89c33fb6-dce9-4097-9be8-f01d502cc11b,Tbl_Server_Admin_Creator,SiteAdministratorExplorer,onLogin
306dac3b-a377-451f-9283-c7be3533e02f,Tbv_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios,Viewer,onSync
9259961c-3ca7-4c1a-9c44-374a4555c270,Tbe_Vs_Canais_Nao_Proprietarios,Explorer,onSync
```

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`